# how to notate type argument for generically polymorphic static method in jshell?

Tags: java, jshell

in plain Java, I can write

```
class P {
    static <A> A id (A x) { return x; }
    static int y = P.<Integer>id(8);
    static String bar = P.<String>id("foo");
}
```

in jshell, I can declare and use `id`

```
jshell> <A> A id (A x) { return x; }
|  created method id(A)

jshell> int x = id(8)
x ==> 8

jshell> String y = id("foo")
y ==> "foo"
```

but I don't see how to make the type argument explicit.

```
jshell> String y = <String>id("foo")
|  Error:
|  illegal start of expression
|  String y = <String>id("foo");
|                     ^
```

What is the name of the implied context class?

Where is the (part of the) jshell specification that would allow me to answer this question? http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222 just mentions a "synthetic class" in "the wrapping". Does not sound like it could be named.

Comment: Use `String y = P.<String>id("foo")`. What is the result?

Comment: try my code in jshell, not using any class P.

Comment: I see. You can declare methods directly in JShell. There must be an implicit class.

Comment: JShell seems to create an anonymous class for each member declaration. I was able to use `REPL.$JShell$9.<String>id("hey")` to invoke the method. It'll vary with each declaration. I don't know what they'll end up using, if anything, as a global identifier.

Comment: Nice! Using tab-completion, I guess.

Comment: I saw something about a class called REPL and went from there, yeah.

Comment: The same problem (and solution) would apply if you wanted to use a function reference? Like `asList("foo").stream().map(::id)`...

Answer (score 1):

Indeed your [link](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222) does not specify the exact nature (like name) of the syntetic class that gets your methods as static methods.

I tried to get the class the snippet is executing in with

```
jshell> new Exception().printStackTrace()
java.lang.Exception
    at REPL.$JShell$17.do_it$($JShell$17.java:8)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-ea/Method.java:531)
    at jdk.internal.jshell.remote.RemoteAgent.commandLoop(jdk.jshell@9-ea/RemoteAgent.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.jshell.remote.RemoteAgent.main(jdk.jshell@9-ea/RemoteAgent.java:62)

jshell> Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].toString()
$15 ==> "do_it$(java:18)"

jshell> Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName()
$16 ==> ""
```

but as you can see, the information is not in stack trace.

The easiest way to circumvent it, is to define your method as a static method in an own class:

```
jshell> class B { static <A> A id(A x) {return x;} }
```

This allows you to call

```
jshell> String y = B.<String>id("foo");
```

and gets the desired result.

Comment: Probably source code of jshell: https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/tree/master/langtools/src/jdk.jshell/share/classes/jdk/jshell